# Firebird 2.5 PSQL Stored Procedure with CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: insert, firebird, temp-tables

I need to create a DDL statement for a temporary table inside a stored procedure 
(Firebird 2.5);

I know that I need to use EXECUTE STATEMENT with dynamic SQL;

Though the stored procedure itself executed and committed successfully,
every time when I run the stored procedure, I get some sort of 
Dynamic SQL Error in IBExpert.

I need the exact syntax and step-by-step approach on how to write a dynamic
SQL code inside a Firebird stored procedure, that creates a global temporary
table (GTT) with 20 columns, and inserts data from another stored procedure (client stored procedure with 20 columns).

I retrieve a part of this data (5 columns) from the GTT (20 columns), 
manipulate it, and develop SSRS reports;  I am not supposed to modify the 
original client stored procedure  at all, since it belongs to our client.

---

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE XYZ   (Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
RETURNS
(
column1,
column2
column3,
column4,
column5
)
-- I need 5 columns in my stored procedure XYZ --
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE STATEMENT
'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MyOwnTable
(
column1,
column2
column3,
column4,
column5,
column6,
column7,
column8,
.
.
column20
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
COMMIT;' ;

EXECUTE STATEMENT
'INSERT INTO MyOwnTable
SELECT *
FROM Client_Stored_Procedure (:Parameter1, :Parameter2, :Parameter3 ); ';

-- Client_Stored_Procedure   :  given by client -- has the same 3 parameters --

EXECUTE STATEMENT
'SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4, SUM(column5) AS "CalculatedColumn"
FROM MyOwnTable 
GROUP BY column1,column2,column3,column4
WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION
INTO  :column1,:column2,:column3,:column4,:CalculatedColumn    ;  ' ;

SUSPEND;

END
```

I am able to commit this stored procedure XYZ; however when I run I get Token Unknown Commit....

I have modified many different parts of this procedure; still get some sort of Token Unknown error;

I am very basic in writing stored procedures in Firebird; can someone help me and give me the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out myself; In PSQL Firebird, any object is like a table in Microsoft T-SQL/SQL Server;  I completely eliminated the need for a temporary table by using this:

```sql
SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4, SUM(column5) AS "CalculatedColumn"
FROM Client_Stored_Procedure (:Parameter1, :Parameter2, :Parameter3 )
GROUP BY column1,column2,column3,column4
```

I am using the Client_Stored_Procedure as a table directly; this cannot be done in Microsoft SQL Server/T-SQL  where a stored procedure is a static data set!

Hence I am freed from creating a  new stored procedure with a global temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebird (and SQL standard) concept of **global** temporary tables differs from how SQL Server handles temporary tables. GTTs are persistent metadata objects (just like normal tables and views), but their content is local to the connection (`ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`) or the transaction (`ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`). So if you need a global temporary table, you should create it once and then use it from your stored procedure (and wherever else you need it), and not attempt to create it within your stored procedure.

The next problem is that you try to execute multiple statements from `EXECUTE STATEMENT`, this is not allowed (only a single statement can be executed), hence the "token unknown" error.

Another problem is that you cannot execute a `COMMIT` from a stored procedure. You could execute the statement in an autonomous transaction, but that would be useless as the created table wouldn't be visible to the current transaction running the stored procedure.

However as you already found out, selectable stored procedures can be seen as yet another view (or table).